# How do i stop webkit animation through js? + fixing image to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a puzzle game website. I'm using `webkit animation` to rotate (and translate) two images.

My plan is to have rotating gears attached to the left and right edge of my page, offset in a way that only half of each image is shown at a time.

The animation works fine but

(1) i am unable to pause it, and

(2) depending on window size the images are moved out of view (with an automatic scrollbar popping up) or into full view.

The setup is pretty simple:
I have 3 divs: one bar at the top with 100% width and two divs with 50% width below as containers for my images.
 I might need to add more below or in between the two divs down the road but for now a solution for this would be good enough^^

For the animation i have a pseudo button on each side which adds a pause class to my images.

**HTML**

```html
  <div id="div-left">
    <p>Hey this is the left div</p>
    <img src="images/zahnrad.png" alt="zahnrad" id="image1">
    <p id="pausebtn1" onclick="pause1()">pause</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-right">
    <p>hey this is the right div</p>
    <img src="images/zahnrad.png" alt="zahnrad" id="image2">
    <p id="pausebtn2" onclick="pause2()">pause</p>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#image1{
    -webkit-animation: rotation-left 30s infinite linear;
}
#image1.paused1::-webkit-progress-value{
    -webkit-animaion-play-state:paused;
    animaion-play-state:paused;
}
#image2{
    align: right;
    -webkit-animation: rotation-right 30s infinite linear;
}
#image2.paused2::-webkit-progress-value{
    -webkit-animaion-play-state:paused;
    animaion-play-state:paused;
}

/* Animations */
@-webkit-keyframes rotation-left{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0px) rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation-right{
    from {
        -webkit-transform:translate(+50%,0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform:translate(+50%,0px) rotate(-359deg);
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function pause1() {
  console.log("pause img 1");
  document.getElementById('image1').classList.toggle("paused1");
}
function pause2() {
  console.log("pause img 2");
  document.getElementById('image2').classList.toggle("paused2");
}
```

So to sum it all up:
I have two images in the wrong places. They are animated. My two buttons are working but trying to pause the animation by adding a paused class doesn't function.
Any help would be appreciated and i'll see if i can add images later

Comment: `::-webkit-progress-value` is for `<progress>` elements only. I don't see any of those in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be targeting `::-webkit-progress-value`, that's for `<progress>` elements. Just toggle the class onto the element:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  square.classList.toggle('paused');
});
```

```css
#square {
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

#square.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
  
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Pause/Resume</button>
<div id="square">Rotate</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response and sorry to answer so late. I'm able to add the class to my images but i get an "unknown property name" error for #image1.paused1 {
    animaion-play-state: paused;
}
so it still doesn't work

Comment: when inspecting the running code i get this though the second line is crossed out with the "unknown property name" error.
`
#image1.paused1 {
    animaion-play-state: paused;
}

#image1 {
    animation: rotation-left 30s infinite linear;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: rotation-left;
}
`

Comment: @nomadDev what browser version are you using? Can you provide an image of the error? You may need to add the vendor prefixes to the animation properties like `-webkit-animation`, `-moz-animation`, etc.

Comment: @skiline3000 I'm on the latest chrome 64bit version 76.0.3809.132 (as i read in another post i saw that the -webkit- prefix was dropped and is no longer necessary.) though it also wont work in the latest firefox version^^

Comment: @nomadDev which code are you inspecting and seeing the error? Your own code, or my example above? I'm running the same version and do not see that error in my example. If it's your own code could you update the OP with the new running code?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IwbKOZj.png here a screenshot
my own though it is functionally pretty much the same.

Comment: only real difference is that i'm adding this to my img element instead of a div

Comment: @nomadDev it looks like you have a typo on that line which is causing the error. It's hard to tell with the strikethrough but I think it's missing the "t" in animation: `animaion-play-state`

Comment: @skiline3000 you are absolutely correct. These are the dumb errors where i read the line hundreds of times and i'm sure everything is right but it's just the auto completion in my brain. Thank you so much and have a great weekend ;D